# No Such Module 'Google Mobile Ads' Error

Tags: swift, admob

I got an error when I add Google Mobile ads into my Xcode.I tried all the answers in Stack through adding and locating the paths but it still says there is an error.Can you please help me on this?

Comment: can you show use the configuration of your project? And the error would also be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution!

I had mistakenly copy-pasted the Google Mobile Ads file in the folder where the ViewController and AppDelegate are found.Then I Cut it back and Paste it to the Framework folder and the error is gone.